# Jersey client response string encoding

Tags: java, encoding, jersey

I'm using jersey client to make a request to a webservice.

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig());
Invocation.Builder builder = client.target("http://someurl.com").request();
String result = builder.get(String.class);
```

Then I got the response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<DATA>some data with é è à characters</DATA>
```

But in my String result, response looks like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<DATA>some data with � � � characters</DATA>
```

How can I tell jersey to properly decode the webservice response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find a workaround for the moment

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig());
Invocation.Builder builder = client.target("http://someurl.com").request();
Response response = builder.get();
String result = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) response.getEntity(), Charsets.ISO_8859_1));
```

`CharStreams` is a Guava class but there are other way to transform an `InputStream` into a `String` with the right `Charset`.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Wizbot, I was having exactly the same problem today.

I wanted to post my java 8 solution without having Guava dependency:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig());
Invocation.Builder builder = client.target("http://someurl.com").request();
Response response = builder.get();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) response.getEntity(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
String result = bufferedReader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```